# why jquery runs confirm twice?

Tags: jquery, ajax, confirm

Any ideas, why that confirm runs twice?

Here I call the function editTableDelete:

```
$('button[name="deleteButton"]').click(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    editTableDelete(row);
});
```

This is the function editTableDelete:

```
function editTableDelete(row) {
    'use strict';

    var data = row.find('input').data();
    data.content = row.find('#contentWrapper').text();
    data.session = $.cookie('PHPSESSID');
    data.type = 'delete';

    if (confirm('Den Eintrag ' + data.content + ' wirklich löschen?'))
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/adminControl/' + data.script,
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                // fade out loading animation
                $("td[contenteditable=true]").find("#updateLoader").fadeOut(400);
                if (result.success) {
                    $(row).fadeOut(400, function() {
                        $(row).remove();
                    });
                    $('.material_alert').html(result.message);
                    $(this).animatedAlert({
                        containerAlert: $("#success_alert"),
                        axisX: "right",
                        axisY: "bottom",
                        autoClose: "true",
                        delayClose: "1000"
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $('.material_alert').html(result.message);
                    $(this).animatedAlert({
                        containerAlert: $("#error_alert"),
                        axisX: "right",
                        axisY: "bottom",
                        autoClose: "true",
                        delayClose: "1000",
                        colorOverlay: $(this).attr("data-color-overlay")
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If i run script, it let me confirm it once and after conformation, comes the second confirmation box with the same entry. Why?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show a little more about the context of this code? The problem is probably not in this snippet

Comment: Which snippet... the php-part?

Comment: No - we need to see the event handler you're running the code under, and also where that event handler is bound. It sounds like you're attaching it multiple times

Comment: You are only showing us the part that runs twice...not the important code you have that triggers this code

Comment: I modified code above. Hope it helps